# cells with formulas that created by python openpyxl appears as empty when viewed in mail

Tags: python, excel, email, outlook, openpyxl

i have a weekly report that i need to do, i chooseed to create it with openpyxl python module, and send it via mail, 
when i open the received mail (outlook), the cells with formulas appears as empty, 
but when downloading the file and open it, the data appears, 
OS fedora 20. parts of the code :

```
# imported modules from openpyxl ...
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
counter = 3
ws.append(row)
for day in data :
    row = ['']*(len(hosts)*2 +5)
    row[0] = day.dayDate

    row[1] ='=SUM(F'+str(counter)+':'+get_column_letter(len(hosts)+5)+str(counter)+\
            ')/(COUNT(F'+str(counter)+':'+get_column_letter(len(hosts)+5)+str(counter)+'))'

    row[2] = '=SUM('+get_column_letter(len(hosts)+6)+str(counter)+':'+\
            get_column_letter(len(hosts)*2+5)+str(counter)+')/COUNT('+\
            get_column_letter(len(hosts)+6)+str(counter)+':'+\
            get_column_letter(len(hosts)*2+5)+str(counter)+')'

    row[3] = '=MAX('+get_column_letter(len(hosts)+6)+str(counter)+':'+\
            get_column_letter(len(hosts)*2+5)+str(counter)+')'

    row[4] = '=_xlfn.STDEV.P('+get_column_letter(len(hosts)+6)+str(counter)\
            +':'+get_column_letter(len(hosts)*2+5)+str(counter)+')'

   counter += 1
```

then, i create from the date some charts, etc.. and save, then send via mail :

```
wb.save(pathToFile+fileName+'.xlsx')
os.system('echo -e "'+msg+'" | mail -s "'+fileName+'" -a '+\
                        pathToFile+fileName+'.xlsx -r '+myUsr+' '+ppl2send2)
```

those are parts of the actual code, any one have an idea why the email don't show the results of the formulas in the cells ? 
Thanks in advance :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl doesn't compute a result for formulas inserted into a spreadsheet; if you open the sheet with excel and save it, the result will have values filled in.

Comment: ok... can I solve this one via script ?!..
p.s. the OS which runs the script don't have Microsoft office,
I tried after saving the file (first time) to reopen it and and save it once more .. but it didn't helped

Comment: I don't see a way with openpyxl (I could have missed it), but I think xlsxwriter allows you to supply a value to display along with the formula. You would have to compute the value yourself, but that seems OK for your example.

Answer (score 0):

opepyxl has a problem with formulas, after you update your excel file you need to open it and save it to get the values generated. There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. (I won't advice you to use this unless you really want it.)

You can automate the process of opening the file and saving it from python before reading it. You can do this by using the win32com module

```
    import win32com.client
    wb.save('PUT YOUR FILE PATH HERE')
    ab = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb2 = ab.Workbooks.Open('PUT YOUR FILE PATH HERE')
    ws = ab.Sheets('PUT THE SHEET NAME HERE')
    ab.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb2.Save()
    wb2.Close()
    ab.Application.Quit()
    #Now you can read from the file and you can see the values generated from the formula
```

2. Or you can use **xlwings** instead of **openpyxl**. if you use this module you don't have to worry about saving the excel file. The module will do it for you.

   ```
   import xlwings
   wb= xlwings.Book('PUT YOUR FILE PATH HERE')
   ws =  wb.sheets[0]
   #Do your update here example ws.range(2, 8).value = 34 
   wb.save()
   wb.close()
   ```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work with Airflow, since airflow appears to be on linux and xlwings is not supported. Is there any other potential solution? I need to be able to reopen the file with python without actually opening and saving the file manually